# Azure SQL, Before trigger?

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a relationship between two entities in my database. So before I create a single row I need to delete the row in the relation entity, like so:

```
   user             userHous
 id     1          1         2
```

So when I delete a user row, it should do a before trigger and delete userHous.

in Mysql this was easily done with my old trigger:

```
USE `db`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`ip` TRIGGER `BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    DELETE FROM user WHERE userid = OLD.userid; 
    DELETE FROM house WHERE userid = OLD.userid; 
end
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this with `{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF }`

I made this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[user]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
    AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM userHouse WHERE userid = userid;
        DELETE FROM user WHERE userid = userid;
    END
```

But this just deletes all rows in both Tables, I guess because I put userid = userid. How do I retrieve the "parameter" which was in the query that made the trigger?

Comment: This syntax looks like SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger]
ON [dbo].[user]
AFTER DELETE
AS
DECLARE @user_id INT
SELECT @user_id = (SELECT userid FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM userHouse WHERE userid = @user_id;
END
```

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem